# Issue in rendering "right arrow" symbol in MS word using java

Tags: java, utf-8, ms-word

Whenever I am inserting the right arrow symbol (→) using the value `&#8594;`, it is getting displayed in the Ms doc file as ? within a rectangle.

Encoding is UTF-8.

If I am replacing `&` by `&amp;` then it is getting displayed as `&amp;#8594;`

Please help me in getting it rendered properly.

Comment: You are generating a MS word file via java? 
Is the font you are using able to display a manually inserted arrow? Have you set the right encoding in java?

Comment: Encoding is UTF-8. I don't know whether it is suitable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the font you are using in your Word document can support the character?...I think some fonts have a limited character range.

How are you inserting it?  It may be the writing of the character that is the problem.